# Linux script for imitating oraenv functionality

Tags: linux

I was trying to write a Linux script for . oraenv
The thing is I have to stop a few servers and then set oracle path before starting the server.
So, I use the command . oraenv and enter the value for the prompts(say "A" for first prompt and "B" for second).
Now, I want to place it in a script.. but I am unable to do so. I tried using spawn also, but its not working as expected.
My linux version says: 2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64

Sorry for the incomplete details. So, I created a shell script(ora1.sh) to set the oracle path. Below is the code:

1. spawn ora.sh
2. expect "ORACLE_SID = "
3. send current

Inside ora.sh file, I have just called the command to set the Oracle env(. orenv)
So, when running the script I get the prompt only for Oracle_SID(which doesn't takes the value I have provided in the send command) and not for ORACLE_HOME. Also, the script terminates[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8vSh.png)
Usually when running the command '. oraenv' it asks for the ORACLE_SID and ORACLE_HOME but when running the script it doesn't asks for ORACLE_HOME.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what does "I am unable to do so" actually mean?

Comment: Posting code and specific error description (or an error log) is highly recommended, whenever possible.

Comment: Apologies... Added more details. Please let me know if anything else required. New here :)